# Appropriate Clustering Algorithm

Tags: clustering

I need to find a good clustering for this data using sci-kit.

[image]

KNN is not appropriate as it creates blobs although these data are linearly separated.

```
import hypertools as hyp
hyp.plot(tocluster,'o', n_clusters=10)
```

[image]

Comment: This page is a good reference for pros and cons of different clustering algos. Maybe gaussian mixture model might be a good starting place for this data https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather not rely on clustering (clearly, DBSCAN would be the first method to try).

Instead, I'd look for a *projection* that removes the correlation (x - y maybe?), then define a grid to separate the data.